# Vue.js 2 - How To Pass Data From Child Component To Parent

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have an app where users create a list of patients. Each patient (child component) contains a name and age. The app will calculate the number of patients and sum of all of the patient's age. How would I pass information from the child component to the parent component?

Note - In my `<report>` component I am currently hard coding the total-age attribute value to 0.

Currently, I have an `addPatient()` method addd to my Vue instance which pushes null into the `patients` array. I feel like I should be pushing something else other then `null` into this array. I have a `v-for` for each `patients`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOgdmW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from child to parent in Vuejs (is it so complicated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334796/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vuejs-is-it-so-complicated)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088646/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-component-in-vue or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410332/vuejs-access-child-components-data-from-parent or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389168/vue-js-passing-events-up-to-parents-in-components